# Searching an Object by it's RealmList

Tags: android, realm

I have a Person object and it has a RealmList of phone numbers.
How can I search a person by a phone number? I'm using Realm for my Android project.
Here are my models:

```
class Person extends RealmObject{
    private RealmList<Contact> emails;
    private RealmList<Contact> phones;
}

class Contact extends RealmObject{
    private String type;
    private String value;
}
```

I need to search a person by email and phone.
Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: Can you edit your post to show us how you declared both the Person and PhoneNumber models?
If I have the property names I could help you out.

Comment: Thanks @EscapeArtist, wait me a moment please!

Comment: @EscapeArtist, I've added my models. Please help me! thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can chain properties with '.'
So in your case you could do:

```
realm.where(Person.class).equalTo("phones.value", whateverYouWant).findAll()
```

Obviously you would replace 'whateverYouWant' with the value you want to search with.

Hope that helps.

Comment: What if you want to search for a contact list of values that has value of 1 in Person A?  Thanks.